# Rendering order in ContentControl - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

There is something that I don't understand regarding ContentControl:
I've a class that inherits from ContentControl, and it overrides the OnRender method. And although **I don't call** base.OnRender(drawingContext) still the content is being rendered...

How come?

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only primitive controls that directly have to draw on the device context, like `Border` or `TextBlock` override `OnRender` to do their jobs. Since most of controls are just a combination of those primitives, they don't draw directly. Instead, they're [measuring and arranging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx#LayoutSystem_Measure_Arrange) their children so that they are at the good position and size.

What you need to override are the methods `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`.

That being said, if you don't want to render anything, it's better to set the `Visibility` of the control to `Collapsed`.